# How to format output (Remove session data) of custom cypher query with Neo4j::Session.query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, cypher, neo4j.rb

I'm using Neo4jrb/Neo4j-core for custom cypher querying in my Rails application. I use this output as json. However, everytime I run a query

Eg:

```
output_hash = Neo4j::Session.query("Match (n) return n limit 1;")
```

Along with the results I also get a lot of unwanted information about the *session* itself.

The following is included for EACH node.

```
      "session": {
    "connection": {
      "parallel_manager": null,
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "User-Agent": "neo4j-gem/7.0.6 (https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j)"
      },
      "params": {},
      "options": {
        "params_encoder": null,
        "proxy": null,
        "bind": null,
        "timeout": null,
        "open_timeout": null,
        "boundary": null,
        "oauth": null
      },
      "ssl": {
        "verify": null,
        "ca_file": null,
        "ca_path": null,
        "verify_mode": null,
        "cert_store": null,
        "client_cert": null,
        "client_key": null,
        "certificate": null,
        "private_key": null,
        "verify_depth": null,
        "version": null
      },
      "default_parallel_manager": null,
      "builder": {
        "handlers": [
          {
            "name": "Faraday::Request::BasicAuthentication",
            "args": [
              "neo4j",
              "root"
            ],
            "block": null
          },
          {
            "name": "FaradayMiddleware::MultiJson::EncodeJson",
            "args": [],
            "block": null
          },
          {
            "name": "FaradayMiddleware::MultiJson::ParseJson",
            "args": [
              {
                "symbolize_keys": true,
                "content_type": "application/json"
              }
            ],
            "block": null
          },
          {
            "name": "Faraday::Adapter::NetHttpPersistent",
            "args": [],
            "block": null
          }
        ],
        "app": {
          "header_value": "Basic bmVvNGo6cm9vdA==",
          "app": {
            "app": {
              "app": {
                "app": {}
              },
              "options": {
                "symbolize_keys": true,
                "content_type": "application/json"
              },
              "content_types": [
                "application/json"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "url_prefix": {
        "scheme": "http",
        "user": null,
        "password": null,
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 7474,
        "path": "/",
        "query": null,
        "opaque": null,
        "fragment": null,
        "parser": {
          "regexp": {
            "SCHEME": "(?-mix:\\A[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9+\\-.]*\\z)",
            "USERINFO": "(?-mix:\\A(?:%\\h\\h|[!$&-.0-;=A-Z_a-z~])*\\z)",
            "HOST": "(?-mix:\\A(?:(?<IP-literal>\\[(?:(?<IPv6address>(?:\\h{1,4}:){6}(?<ls32>\\h{1,4}:\\h{1,4}|(?<IPv4address>(?<dec-octet>[1-9]\\d|1\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]|\\d)\\.\\g<dec-octet>\\.\\g<dec-octet>\\.\\g<dec-octet>))|::(?:\\h{1,4}:){5}\\g<ls32>|\\h{,4}::(?:\\h{1,4}:){4}\\g<ls32>|(?:(?:\\h{1,4}:)?\\h{1,4})?::(?:\\h{1,4}:){3}\\g<ls32>|(?:(?:\\h{1,4}:){,2}\\h{1,4})?::(?:\\h{1,4}:){2}\\g<ls32>|(?:(?:\\h{1,4}:){,3}\\h{1,4})?::\\h{1,4}:\\g<ls32>|(?:(?:\\h{1,4}:){,4}\\h{1,4})?::\\g<ls32>|(?:(?:\\h{1,4}:){,5}\\h{1,4})?::\\h{1,4}|(?:(?:\\h{1,4}:){,6}\\h{1,4})?::)|(?<IPvFuture>v\\h+\\.[!$&-.0-;=A-Z_a-z~]+))\\])|\\g<IPv4address>|(?<reg-name>(?:%\\h\\h|[!$&-.0-9;=A-Z_a-z~])*))\\z)",
            "ABS_PATH": "(?-mix:\\A\\/(?:%\\h\\h|[!$&-.0-;=@-Z_a-z~])*(?:\\/(?:%\\h\\h|[!$&-.0-;=@-Z_a-z~])*)*\\z)",
            "REL_PATH": "(?-mix:\\A(?:%\\h\\h|[!$&-.0-;=@-Z_a-z~])+(?:\\/(?:%\\h\\h|[!$&-.0-;=@-Z_a-z~])*)*\\z)",
            "QUERY": "(?-mix:\\A(?:%\\h\\h|[!$&-.0-;=@-Z_a-z~\\/?])*\\z)",
            "FRAGMENT": "(?-mix:\\A(?:%\\h\\h|[!$&-.0-;=@-Z_a-z~\\/?])*\\z)",
            "OPAQUE": "(?-mix:\\A(?:[^\\/].*)?\\z)",
            "PORT": "(?-mix:\\A[\\x09\\x0a\\x0c\\x0d ]*\\d*[\\x09\\x0a\\x0c\\x0d ]*\\z)"
          }
        }
      },
      "proxy": null
    },
    "resource_data": {
      "extensions": {},
      "node": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node",
      "relationship": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship",
      "node_index": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node",
      "relationship_index": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/relationship",
      "extensions_info": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext",
      "relationship_types": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/types",
      "batch": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/batch",
      "cypher": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
      "indexes": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index",
      "constraints": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/constraint",
      "transaction": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction",
      "node_labels": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/labels",
      "neo4j_version": "3.0.1"
    },
    "resource_url": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/"
  }
```

The *session data* seems to contain a lot of sensitive information and so I can't directly use the output.

I'd like to avoid this and just get simple, essential, output to my cypher queries and no extra information. Is there a config setting that I can use to accomplish this?

Thank you.

**Update:**
I'm actually using **Neo4jrb/Neo4j** (which includes Neo4j-core) as a ActiveModel replacement for few basic tasks in this project. And custom queries for the main tasks.

Further inspection:

As long as an ActiveNode model is defined, I get a clear response without any extra(session) data. But only the properties defined in the model file are returned.

```
class User
    include Neo4j::ActiveNode

    property :name, type: String
    property :email, type: String
end
```

This is working fine for the User model, any properties not declared in the model file(but present in the database) are ignored by default according to the documentation.

**My problem:** My graph has certain nodes that will have many different property keys that cannot be hardcoded beforehand into the model file (Reason for using column-less DB). I cannot declare all the properties of these nodes in the model.

So I'm trying to do a custom cypher query as Neo4j::Session.query(q) But the JSON response is too cluttered with *session data* haphazardly. Processing this response with code is resulting in a convoluted code because there doesn't seem to be a consistent way the *session data* is included between results(nodes, edges, aggregators.)

I'm looking for a solution or a way out.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you're getting all of that data, but there is a setting in the upcoming 8.0 which will allow you to change the way things are wrapped, including returning hash representations of the results

Comment: Sorry, I needed to go offline quickly last night.  You say that all of that data is included for each node.  How are you getting the data?  It looks like the JSON response, but then the `neo4j` / `neo4j-core` gems wrap nodes / relationships in objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back Brian. I've updated the post with details. Yes it is a JSON response. When a model is declared it gives me declared properties and no clutter. When there is no model, I get all properties but also the session data clutter.

Comment: I'm sorry, a correction. I get an `Enumerator`. Which is converted into an Array of Structs by the `to_a` method. `[#<struct n=CypherNode xx (70157506237380)>,...]` is the array. In my application I directly do an `render json: Enumerator`, which converts the data to json. Furthermore, the json includes data from Faraday too. Maybe if some variables are getting passed along to Neo4j-core, it is including it with each row data?

Comment: I could be out of my depth here. But going through the source code, I find this line peculiar and a potential cause of my problem. [Neo4j-core CypherResponse Class](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/blob/master/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb#L59)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Brian for your help.
To summarise:

The `session` key in the output is because `Neo4j-core` returns the respective object(node/edge) whenever possible, refer [this line here](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/blob/master/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb#L86) in the source code. Both the CypherNode and CypherRelationship classes have the @session variable and when their objects are converted to JSON/Hash/YAML, the `session` data is being included auto.

One option is to write your own custom methods and extend the class to give cleaner JSON output. Brian mentions that upcoming 8.0 will give syntax options in the response. Or you can write your custom code in your app to process the response from `Neo4j-core`.

I finally ended up doing the latter as below:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

    def test
        q = "Match (n) return n;"
        data = Neo4j::Session.query(q)
        output = clean_response(data)

        render json: output
    end

    private

    def clean_response(data)
        # data = Enumerator
        data = data.map(&:to_h)
        # data = [ { x: => CypherXxxx <Object>},...   ]
        data.map! do |entry|
            hash = JSON.parse(entry.to_json)
            # Clean json of the entry
            entry = delete_keys(hash)
        end
    end

    def delete_keys(hash)
        # Recursive func to delete session/response_hash from a hash of any depth 
        if(hash.class == Hash)
            hash.delete("session") if hash.keys.include?("session")
            hash.delete("response_hash") if hash.keys.include?("response_hash")
            hash.each_value{|value|
              value = delete_keys(value)
            }
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems like there might be a couple of things going on ;)

Firstly, regarding undefined properties, there's actually been an issue thread here about that recently:

https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/1209

For now you should be able to use `user._persisted_obj.props` to get all of the properties for the node, even if they aren't defined in the `ActiveNode` model.

Regarding the JSON, I think I see what you're saying.  I think, actually, that the `Enumerator` doesn't have very good support for rendering to JSON.  I've seen people have this problem before, but it just clicked on why.  For now, try:

```
render json: query_result_enumerator.map(&:to_h)
```

That should convert to an array of `Hash` objects and Hash as well as the enclosed node/rel objects should all support being JSONified.

Comment: Thank you for the ._persisted_obj.props and the github issue reference. I can move forward with my work and not be stalled. Regarding the JSON: it still includes the `session` data in each row. I believe this is because `session` is being auto-included inside each row (nodes/edges objects) as a key-value pair. The only solution I saw was to remove `session` from each row of the JSON, but felt I might as well see if the gem is at fault and fix it if possible. I'll play around with the source code and get back to you.

Comment: You are right. The [CypherNode](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/blob/master/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_node.rb#L10), [CypherRelationship](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/blob/master/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_relationship.rb#L10), labels, etc all classes naturally have a @session variable. Which is getting converted into a key-value pair in JSON.